# Split line with multiple delimiters in Unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed, split

I have the below lines in a file

```
id=1234,name=abcd,age=76
id=4323,name=asdasd,age=43
```

except that the real file has many more `tag=value` fields on each line.
I want the final output to be like

```
id,name,age
1234,abcd,76
4323,asdasd,43
```

I want all values before (left of) the `=` to come out as separated with a `,` as the first row and all values after the (right side) of the `=` to come below for in each line

Is there a way to do it with `awk` or `sed`? Please let me know if for loop is required for the same?

I am working on Solaris 10; the local `sed` is *not* GNU `sed` (so there is no `-r` option, nor `-E`).

Comment: Please mention your sed version. Thanks

Comment: Which version of Solaris do you use?

Comment: Get rid of the obfuscating `...`s and just post a complete, testable example.

Comment: I am sorry Ed. Those were just meant to show that the number of fields are unknown . So the extraction is totally based on pattern matching without considering the number/name of fields.

Comment: I understand the intent but find some other way to express your requirements than cluttering up what should simply be concise, testable sample input/output with text that doesn't actually exist and we somehow have to deal with when testing our proposed solution for you.

Comment: I shall surely keep that in mind . :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FILE=yourfile.txt

# first line (header)
cat "$FILE" | head -n 1 | sed -r "s/=[^,]+//g"

# other lines (data)
cat "$FILE" | sed -r "s/[^,]+=//g"
```

Comment: Hi Tomas,That was quick.Thanks.But sed -r comes out to say illegal option.Is there any alternative?

Comment: Interesting, works for me here. But I'm on Linux, so it is possible that your sed is some different version.

Comment: That is true . I am at the office and this thing in front of me is Solaris.

Comment: @TomasM: replace first sed command by `sed 's/=[^,]\{1,\}//g'` and second by `sed 's/[^,]\{1,\}=//g'` to work with GNU and solaris' sed.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[,=]"; OFS="," }
NR==1 {
    for (i=1;i<NF;i+=2) {
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i<(NF-1) ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}
{
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) {
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
id,name,age
1234,abcd,76
4323,asdasd,43
```

Assuming they don't really exist in your input, I removed the `...`s etc. that were cluttering up your example before running the above. If that stuff really does exist in your input, clarify how you want the text "(n number of fields)" to be identified and removed (string match? position on line? something else?).

EDIT: since you like the brevity of the `cat|head|sed; cat|sed` approach posted in another answer, here's the equivalent in awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{h=$0;gsub(/=[^,]+/,"",h);print h} {gsub(/[^,]+=/,"")} 1' file
id,name,age
1234,abcd,76
4323,asdasd,43
```

Comment: Wow. Actually , I had the pseudo code for the above in mind but could not realise it in syntax. Amazing as it is , I'd for the solution mentioned by Tomas and Cyrus since it just takes one line. 
Thanks a ton though.

Comment: No, the posted cat+head+sed solution does NOT take just one line and it uses UUOC and it uses multiple tools+pipes when one would do and it takes 2 passes of the file, and it would not work if your input was coming from a stream instead of a file. Good luck!

Comment: Correct. 

That's why ,I have used the one mentioned in the comment section
First I did sed 's/=[^,]\{1,\}//g' on the file which takes out the headers and second sed 's/[^,]\{1,\}=//g' which brings out all the values. 

I think this is cool right ? :)

Comment: Whether you use the sed commands from the answer you chose or the sed commands from the comments below it, my comment above applies. Obviously, use it if you like and as long as you aren't worried about efficiency, reusabailty, enhancability, etc. it should work just fine.

Comment: Since you like the `cat|head|sed; cat|sed` approach posted in another answer, I edited my answer to show the equivalent approach in awk.

Comment: Hmmm..I see the other side now .

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r '1 s/^/id,name,age\n/;s/id=|name=|age=//g' my_file
```

edit: or use

```
sed '1 s/^/id,name,age\n/;s/id=\|name=\|age=//g'
```

output

```
id,name,age
1234,abcd,76 ...(n number of fields)
4323,asdasd,43...
```

Comment: try "sed --help" and see what arguments has the description "use extended regular expressions in the script."..then use that argument...

Comment: -e -f and -n are only supported .Is there an alternative

Comment: take out the -r option..and it should work fine since the pattern is also BRE

Comment: Actually the thing is , that the fields in the line are not known. That is the catch . If you see my question again, you'll notice.
So if columns are known then this is fine .

Comment: my apologies use the next solution in my edited answer

Comment: Umm...actually.This is not quite the thing.
You see, like instead of name ,age ,and all I would want 
1)anything before the "=" as first line separated by comma(this becomes the header)
2)anything after the "=" as the rest of the lines(this the data )

I want this to go in csv format , so I want it like that .I don't want to hard code the column names,instead I wish that they picked from the command line via pattern matching.

Comment: Yes..based on the output..the command line work on my side as expected...I will add the output on my side in my question for reference

Answer (score 0):

The following simply combines the best of the sed-based answers so far, showing you can have your cake and eat it too.  If your sed does not support the -r option, chances are that -E will do the trick; all else failing, one can replace R+ by RR* where R is [^,]

```
sed -r '1s/=[^,]+//g; s/[^,]+=//g'
```

(That is, the portable incantation would be:

```
sed "1s/=[^,][^,]*//g; s/[^,][^,]*=//g"
```

)

Comment: Could you please put all the alternatives down here? I using solaris and -r and -E is not supported.